# Если изменится html сайта, то мобильное приложение тоже работать не будет?

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup

Создаю приложение для сайта с использованием библиотеки Jsoup. Но если вдруг html сайта изменится, то моё приложение тоже работать не будет. Как этого избежать?

```
String url = "http://auto-aksrzn.ru/detskie-kresla/siger/siger-buster-fix-krasnyy/";
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    Elements sections = doc.select("body");
    String text=doc.select("meta[name=description]").attr("content");
```

например, если изменится name в примере кода

Comment: В общем случае этого никак не избежать.

Comment: Как показывает практика, люди очень редко меняют имена своих блоков на сайте. Это раз. Второй момент - а как ваша программа ещё будет понимать, откуда добывать инфу? Можете, конечно, научить ее распознавать образы, чтобы она аки человек сама понимала, что и откуда ей нужно брать. Но игра не стоит свеч. Так что если вдруг админ сайта и решит менять name блока - просто обновите прогу

Comment: Если Вы будете вытаскивать только мета-теги то с большой степенью вероятности они там будут всегда. Если же вы будете таскать цены и прочее из каталога, то тут увы и ах -  придётся подстраиваться при изменении вёрстки. Но сказать по правде с Jsoup не долго будет переписать парсер.

Answer (score 1):

Если Ваше приложение заточено на вёрстку html-документов, то да, при его изменении, возможно, сломается и мобильное приложение. Именно поэтому владельцы сайтов, зачастую предоставляют отдельное API под мобильные приложения.

Если парсинг html-документов - это единственный вариант, то я бы посоветовал сделать свой простенький backend на котором будет парсинг документов и API для мобильного приложения.

В случае, если Вы поймёте, что структура html-документов на сайте поменялась и парсинг больше не работает, вы сможете быстро решить проблему фиксом на backend'е. Таким образом мобильное приложение, уже выложенное в публичный доступ в маркет не нужно будет тащить через ревью и выпуск новой версии.